# How to grep for a particular pattern exactly two times in perl?

Tags: regex, perl

I have a pattern,
Let it be this,

`pppoe   lg id 827 vlan-id 100 pppoe user@local         local     Jan  3 14:41:20`

from this i wanted to grep for the pattern 'pppoe' and want to ensure that it is present exactly two times.

`pppoe   lg id 827 vlan-id 100 pppo user@local         local     Jan  3 14:41:20`

here `pppoe` is present only once, other is `pppo`, this time it should not match.

Answer (score 4):

A straight forward way is to put the matches in an array and check the number of items:

```
my $str = "pppoe lg id 827 vlan-id 100 pppoe user\@local local Jan 3 14:41:20";
my @count = $str =~ /pppoe/g;
if (scalar @count == 2) {
    print "MATCH exactly two times\n";
}
```

or, as suggested by [mpapec](https://stackoverflow.com/users/223226/mpapec):

```
print "MATCH\n" if scalar @{[ $str =~ /pppoe/g ]} == 2;
```

Comment: Did you mean `/\bpppoe\b/g`?

Comment: @Kenosis no, not really? The OP doesn't say it has to be a separate word, only a "pattern".

Comment: There is also the [Goatse Operator](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/secret-perl-operators/#goatse) but to me that's both obscure and scary...

Comment: That's a good point.  Perhaps I'm reading to much into the OP's examples where pppoe is a separate word.

Comment: `@{[ $str =~ /pppoe/g ]}` slightly better than goatse.

Comment: @mpapec Yes, that would be as in: `print "MATCH\n" if scalar @{[ $str =~ /pppoe/g ]} == 2;`

Comment: Here are some alternatives, but I would not use majority of them https://eval.in/90777

Comment: `scalar`'s not needed in front of either array, since `==` forces scalar context.

Comment: @Kenosis I know. It's me wanting to be explicit for the sake of clarity. Don't know which is the best approach in a public discussion likely to be read by Perl-beginners. Coming from another language you might expect something like `"if (count.length == 2)"`, so I tend to add the `scalar` just as a reminder that we're counting items, not comparing arrays. A matter of taste I guess?

Comment: Excellent response to the use of `scalar`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
^((?!pppoe).)*(pppoe)((?!pppoe).)*\2((?!pppoe).)*$
```

Refer **[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/hG0aH7)**

**Explanation :**

[image: Explanation]

Comment: -1: And how will this NOT match on three or more `ppoe` in the string? *"ensure that it is present exactly two times"*

Comment: @user3205318 I doubt it? `/^(pppoe){2}$/` matches the exact string `pppoepppoe` and nothing else.

Comment: @SujithPS Did you try your code? It still matches on `pppoe lg pppoe id 827 vlan-id 100 pppoe user@local local Jan 3 14:41:20` which has three `pppoe`. It should only match on exactly two.

Comment: @grebneke : that is the case. i should only look for the pattern pppoe. if it is pppo or pppe or something else then it should not match.

Comment: @grebneke : Thank you for your comments . Once again I updated my answer.

Comment: @SujithPS Sorry, still not correct. It matches `ppoe lg id 827 vlan-id 100 ppoe user@local local Jan 3 14:41:20` which doesn't contain a single `pppoe`.

Comment: @grebneke : Ya. I just used my code to match ppoe ,not for pppoe , But now I updated that also . :)

Comment: @SujithPS Alright, that seems to work :) Still not easy to read though.

Answer (score 0):

All that is necessary is

```
if ($str =~ /pppoe.*pppoe/) {
  ...
}
```